# How to split summary address received as response of ordnance survey address base

Tags: united-kingdom, address-parsing

I am using an API to fetch search response from ordinance survey address base, the result includes a summary address field which contains full address in one line.

The result can be ambiguous as summary address can contain any type of details in it. An address can have 4 or 5 comma separated fields or sometimes even 8 or 9 comma separated fields. 
example 1 : "results": [{
    "address": [{
      "uprn": xxxxxxxx,
      "summary_address": "**2 Wakefield, Edeinnburh, EH9 6TL**",
      "matchscore": 100
    }

example 2: "results": [{
    "address": [{
      "uprn": xxxxxxxxx,
      "summary_address": "**Domino Piza, Unit 10, 100 sample Road, Bishopbrig, G44 2AB**",
      "matchscore": 100
    }

I have no clue how to split these fields properly and identify them. Is there any fixed format for this?
I want to split address and identify each field either as house number, house name, road, locality, town etc

Note: the address used in above examples are fake and do not correspond to any real data

Comment: Ordnance Survey is Great Britain (not including Northern Ireland) the data you need is in the addressbase specification see 2. AddressBase Core Structure https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/product-support/tech-spec/addressbase-core-technical-specification.pdf

Comment: sounds like you should get the other address fields back from the API to give what you want rather than use the summary line